# Why does my structure assignment fail in C language？

Tags: objective-c, c

Why does my structure assignment fail in C language？
I have a class A: define a structure

```
typedef struct{
    int sockfd;
    on_av_frame_cb av_frame_cb;
    on_av_frame_cb rtp_cb;
    on_error_cb error_cb;
    uint8_t *p_buf;
    uint8_t *v_buf;
    uint8_t *a_buf;
    int  rtp_flag;
}udp_client_t;
```

Then I call in class B:

```
static udp_client_t client;
int jldv_create_client(int src_port,int port ,const char *dst_ip){


udp_client_t *udpClient = &client;

assert(udpClient != NULL);
const char *c_ip = dst_ip;

memset(udpClient, 0, sizeof(udp_client_t));

int ret = create_client(src_port, port, c_ip, &udpClient);

if (ret != 0) {

    goto err_output;
}

udpClient->av_frame_cb = (on_av_frame_cb )onVideoFrame;
udpClient->error_cb = on_error;



if (rtp_create(&udpClient) < 0) { ///above problem
    goto err_output;
}

printf("rtp_client:%d \n",udpClient->rtp_flag);
return 0;

err_output:
destroy_client(udpClient);
return -1;

}
```

In the above problem, I used the C class method:

```
int rtp_create(udp_client_t **data)
{
    logi("%s", __func__);

    udp_client_t *udpClient = *data;
    if(udpClient)
    {

        udpClient->rtp_flag = 1;


        memset(&rtp_cxt, 0, sizeof(rtp_context_t));
        int ret = init_server();
        if (ret < 0)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        rtp_cxt.nalu = alloc_nalu(MAX_FRAME_SIZE);//
        if (!rtp_cxt.nalu)
        {
            loge("alloc nalu failed");
            return -2;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        loge("%s: data is null", __func__);
        return -3;
    }

    printf("udpClient after==>%d \n",udpClient->rtp_flag);
    return 0;
}
```

However, the result of printing is:

```
udpClient after==>1 
rtp_client:0
```

supplement:

```
int create_client(int src_port, int dst_port, const char *dst_ip, udp_client_t **client)
{
  udp_client_t *udpClient = *client;
  assert(udpClient != NULL);
  memset(udpClient, 0, sizeof(udp_client_t));

  printf("create_client:%p\n",udpClient);

  udpClient->port = src_port;

  if (pthread_create(&udpClient->recv_tid, NULL, udp_receiver_runnable, (void *) udpClient) != 0)
  {
    loge("Failed to start new thread");
    goto err_output;
  }
  return 0;
  err_output:
  memset(udpClient, 0, sizeof(udp_client_t));
  return -10;
}
```

Why is that? Did i use something wrong?

Comment: Are you using C or Objective-C? C doesn't have classes.

Comment: Well I think you also forget a part of the code, we are missing the `create_client` function

Comment: em...I create the client like this:
int create_client(int src_port, int dst_port, const char *dst_ip, udp_client_t **client)
{
    udp_client_t *udpClient = *client;
    assert(udpClient != NULL);
    memset(udpClient, 0, sizeof(udp_client_t));

    printf("create_client:%p\n",udpClient);
    
    udpClient->port = src_port;

    if (pthread_create(&udpClient->recv_tid, NULL, udp_receiver_runnable, (void *) udpClient) != 0)
    {
  goto err_output;
 }
    return 0;
err_output:
    memset(udpClient, 0, sizeof(udp_client_t));
    return -10;
}

Comment: @jackenchen Don't put code in comments, it's totally unreadable. Edit the question.

Comment: Why do you pass double pointers to your functions, instead of just pointers to the structures?

Comment: em..I use C to do something, like receive data，and then,I use Objective-C to use the C interface

Comment: I suggest you step through the code with a debugger, to see where the variable is changing. You probably have some undefined behavior in one of the functions you call after doing `udpClient->rtp_flag = 1;`

Comment: OK，I try it now

Comment: Just use valgrind to highlight memory issue.

Comment: place edits to your question in the question itself, not in comments.  Mark them as EDITs.

Comment: The posted code, even with all the edits, does not compile.  Amongst many other things, it is missing the needed `#include` statements for the needed header files. After you post those needed statements, we would be in a much better position to help you.